# Does sending an AJAX request in Apache start a new process?

Tags: php, ajax

A few simple questions for someone who knows how the Apache server works I think.

1. Does sending an AJAX .send request to a .php file start a new process in the background?
2. If so, when does that process end?
3. When I send multiple AJAX requests to the same php file, will the server create multiple processes of the same file, or is there a way to send all requests to a single PHP process with an inifinite loop inside it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache handles requests along the following principles:

1. Apache leaves some spare processes/threads to handle client requests. Incoming connection from a client is handled by an idle process. If there is no idle process apache starts a new one unless maximum number of processes is reached. In that case, your request is waiting for some other process to finish its work.
2. The process/thread finishes when there are too many idle processes or the process has served a maximum number of requests.
3. Ajax requests are handled by PHP script one at a time. For every ajax request your script gets run from start. You can have "long running" PHP script continuously reading the input and sending output, but it will block server resources and be subject to timeouts on many levels. Generally it is not a good idea to use on a heavy server like apache, less so for a busy site.
   If you need continuous browser-server communication then HTML5 websockets with appropriate server provides a good solution see eg. http://socket.io

Comment: How do I make multiple reads from JavaScript in a single PHP program?
My "server" is not an internet server, and is limited to 1 connection at a time. How would I set up a "long running" PHP script you mentioned?

Comment: There should be a way for example to implement Websockets server inside running PHP script, but that's definitely bad idea for your purpose (and it is a bad idea almost always). After reading your [problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21974014/php-and-javascript-sharing-a-unix-socket-between-php-programs-through-javascrip) - opening a unix socket and accepting it on the C program side will be MUCH faster then processing a request inside apache+php itself. Make some tests.

Comment: The C program is a socket server, and the PHP script is just supposed to connect to the C server once, and then send a message via socket on each button click/release. The problem is triggering PHP to send the message, because PHP can't detect button clicks (only JavaScript can).

Comment: Sure. What I wanted to say is, that creating the local socket is very cheap (performance-wise) compared to the cost of processing HTTP request in Apache+PHP which you do anyway.

Comment: Cool, I didn't know that :D So, if I understood you correctly, you're saying that processing a button click event in JavaScript and doing an AJAX call would take more time than initializing a socket connection in the called PHP script?

Comment: Handling ajax call on the server (apache+php) will take much more time than creating local socket between php and your "C server". Do some tests.

Comment: How would I do some tests? Do you have a link where I could learn time measuring in PHP and JS? Also, thank you very much for your help, it means a lot to me :D I may even make the deadline now.

Comment: Total request time (including delays caused by network, which may be significant here) can be easily checked eg. in firebug. Or you can measure the request time in javascript yourself by checking `new Date().getTime()` before AJAX request and after you get the response. In php code, check [microtime](http://www.php.net/microtime) function for the same purpose. Try to measure the socket create/connect time in PHP, you will be supprised how fast it is.

Answer (score 1):

An ajax request has no difference than any other request from the webserver side. The difference is at the client side, on how the browser will handle the request.

Multiple requests to the same php script, are handled like multiple requests to different php scripts, and the server will handle them seperately and simultaneously.

If you use exclusive locks, or you use file sessions and only for requests within the same session, the requests will be processed one by one (When you start a file session the session is exclusively locked and it is auto unlocked at request's end).

When the process of the request is completed, all the variables that were created within the execution are destroyed. If you need persistance within different requests you could use an opcode caching mechanism like the [php-apc](https://www.php.net/apc/)

> is there a way to send all requests to a single PHP process with an
> inifinite loop inside it?

Why you need this?

Comment: Basically I don't want to reinitialize a socket address variable on each button click, and I can't share the variable using AJAX or APC because it's a resource variable type.
So, I want to send requests from JavaScript to a running (initialized) PHP process using AJAX.
I explained my entire problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21974014/php-and-javascript-sharing-a-unix-socket-between-php-programs-through-javascrip).